# Ionic 4 - Keyboard pushing content up

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic 4 App. I'm having the issue that whenever the user opens the keyboard, the App content moves all up and then when the keyboard is closed, part of the header is hiding behind my phone's statusbar.

In Ionic 3 I knew this could be solved modifying the styles of ion-scroll as a workaround but here that's not working.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a view that has a toolbar and content. I managed to solved it using `position:fixed;` in scss file. Now only the content scrolls which is acceptable for my app. The toolbar remains in the right place. It would be nice to have a generic solution for this

Comment: Hi @dev , I updated to Ionic 4.2.0  and it got fixed itself. Maybe it was just a bug of the 4.0.0 version I was using

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updating my Ionic angular to 4.2.0 version fixed this. It seemed to be a bug with Ionic 4.0.0

Comment: it could be called an issue, not a bug :)

Comment: still the same for me!

Comment: I can still see the issue in iOS in @ionic/angular 4.11.7  Ionic CLI: 5.4.1 and Cordova latest 9.0

Answer (score 1):

for ionic versions greaters or equals than 5.0.0  , If you use ionic-content, you just set **slot="fixed"** and have to give his custom css property **--offset-bottom** the value **0 !important** in your component's css file:

```
    .ionic-content {
       --offset-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
```

The content will come back to his initial position when the keyboard is hidden.
But this solution is not working in Ionic 4.7.1

Comment: Do you mean ion-content? And does this also work if you have a ion-footer?

Comment: it breaks the content, pushes it up all the way to the top